# Execution Priority in custom Attributes in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

I have two custom attributes in my asp.net mvc(C#) application.

```
[CustAttribute1()]
[CustAttribute2()]
```

When I use those attributes to my actions, which will get executed first?

```
[CustAttribute1()]
[CustAttribute2()]
public ActionResult Index()
{
```

Can I use more than one custom attributes for my actions? If so, in the above Action, which custom attribute will execute first?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the [Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.order.aspx) property.

```
[CustAttribute1(Order=2)]
[CustAttribute2(Order=1)]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What about the attributes which are added in `filters` in `FilterConfig` (Mvc 5)

Comment: Without specifying the Order, does the order of appearance is the order of invocation?

Comment: It's true only for FilterAttribute