# C# multiple Attributes Calling Sequence

Tags: c#

I have multiple attributes i want to apply on controller .which i need to call them in order of sequence ,because if the first Attributes executes ,i initialize variables that the following attribute would use.

```
[AuthorizeLicense]
[MerchantLoggedIn]
[MerchantAuthorize]
public class MerchantController : BaseController
{
}
```

Definition of my attributes

```
 public class AuthorizeLicense:AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override  bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        if(somecondition is true){
     //initialize variables for next attribute use;
        }

    }

    protected override  void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {


    }


}
```

Next Attribute

```
  public class MerchantLoggedIn:AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override  bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

          //use initialize variables from previous attribute 


    }

    protected override  void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {


    }


}
```

The challenge i am facing is that the Attributes are not called in the sequence as i have defined them on the class ; that is from top to bottom.
Please help ..what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like broken design to me, if an attribute works only if another one is also set, then you might encapsulate it into the latter in any way. What are you doing if any developer provides only one attribute?

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but could you pass the other 2 attributes into the first as parameters, but if Im honest I don't like the idea or attributes depending on each other. Edit. HimBromBeere beat me to it

Comment: If MerchantLoggedIn always needs AuthorizeLicense you could inherit from AuthorizeLicense and just use the one attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Order parameter

```
[AuthorizeLicense(Order = 1)]
[MerchantLoggedIn(Order = 2)]
public class ...
```

See [Execution Priority in custom Attributes in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770550/execution-priority-in-custom-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I have been searching this for weeks even months. Thank you very much @AndrewSilver